# Primitive operation on algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, analytics

I am doing an analysis of algorithm and stuck on `for and while loop`

Suppose we have a for loop with

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
```

so assignment `i = 0` = 1

`i < n = n+1` (it will run n time and the last checking in which loop will be false would be n+1)

here is the confusion

`i++` --> i++ will also run n times but it is doing two different jobs, increment, and assignment. Would it be 2n or just n?

Same is in while loop

`while (i<n):`  Will be 2n?

I am working on Big O.

Thank you

Comment: yes. you're right.

Comment: Why would the fact that `i++` is doing 2 jobs affect how many times the loop runs?

Comment: "Would it be 2n or just n?" What is "it" referring to? Would _what_ be 2n?

Comment: Are you talking about [Big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) analysis?

Comment: @Kayaman Yes Big O

Comment: @Sweeper `i++` is `i=i+1`, so two operations, assignment, and increment, and if it runs `n` times then would it be `2n`

Comment: @AHF Oh so you are talking about Big O! You can make that clearer by [edit]ing your question. O(2n) and O(n) are equivalent though. You could also argue that your code is O(3n) because of the comparison in each iteration. You could also say it's O(kn) where k is constant because each operation written in Java is compiled into many java byte code instructions. You could go on and on like this. But the point is, these complexities are all equivalent to O(n).

Comment: I am looking here https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall02/V22.0310-002/chapters/chapter-01.html counting primitive operation and they counting it as 2n

Answer (score 0):

Normally one assignment is equivalent to one operation or "step". This is because usually the asymptotic run-time of an algorithm is measured, using the [big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) where constants don't matter.

I would normally count `i++` as one operation. So, to answer your question, assuming all these loops do is increment `i`, the run-time would be `O(n)`. However, even if you count it as two, the run-time would still be `O(n)`.

Comment: To expand on this answer, the reason why it's `O(n)` and not `O(2n)` is because constants multipliers are ignored in Big-O notation.

Comment: But if I only count `i=i+1` so its performing 2 operations, addition, and assignment, so would it be 2n?

Comment: As many people have mentioned above, you can even justify it being `kn`, since you can decompose these operations into Java byte-code instructions.
If you choose your elementary operations to be assignment and addition, then yes, strictly speaking this loop would perform `2n` operations.
 Asymptotic run-time allows you to generalize away such details and say that this loop runs in `O(n)`, since the constant in front of the `n` (i.e. the "depth" of your analysis) doesn't change the asymptotic behavior of the program.